# How to print text or values in advantage database?

Tags: advantage-database-server

I want to know if I can display text or values of the variables in the advantage database, as well as in SQL server with the PRINT command.

Answer (score 0):

You can only raise exceptions to the client [using RAISE](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/index.html?master_raise.htm).

Everything else must be returned as a data set.

There is an [undocumented `EXECUTE PRINT` command](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/questions/5772/what-does-execute-dprint-and-execute-print-do-and-why-is-it-not-documented) though, but I still don't know what that does ...